# i don't know how to solve this Run time check failure #2-S error in ms visual studio C++

Tags: c++

My expected results is correctly printed but debug error message(Run time check failure #2-S) is keep printed.
I don't know what's wrong with my code
please help me

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

    int  N, S,J, K,k,i,j,l,m,n,cnt;

    scanf("%d", &k);
    int A[50];
    int B[50];
    if (k <= 50) {
        for (i = 1; i < k + 1; i++) {
            cnt = 0;
            B[50] = 0;
            scanf("%d %d %d %d\n", &N, &S, &J, &K);
            for (j = 0; j < K-1 ; j++) {
                scanf("%d ", &B[j]);
            }
            scanf("%d", &B[K-1]);
            n = (N - S) / J+1;
            for (l = 0;l<= n ; l++) {

                    for (m = 0; m < K ; m++) {
                        if (S + (J+1)*l == B[m]) cnt++;
                    }

            }

            A[i] = cnt;
        }

        for (i = 1; i < k + 1; i++) {
            printf("#%d %d\n", i, A[i]);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: u reach the end of ur array, array with 50 size can be accessed trough at 49 but u reach even at 51

Comment: All of the +1 and -1 madness in this should be nuked from orbit. C and C++ are zero-index based, as the sooner you embrace rather that fight that the easier life will become.

Comment: How can you "expect" any results from this code with variable names like that?

Comment: @gilhyun A couple of suggestions.  Since this is doing the `<stdio.h>` `printf` and `scanf` thing, you should probably remove the C++ tag, since those are C constructs that have far better replacements in C++.  And yes,to emphasize what @BarisYakut said, you will find C a whole lot easier to use if you give your variables meaningful names.  It costs absolutely nothing at runtime, and makes the code vastly easier to read and understand.  Both for others, and for yourself when you come back and look at something three or four years after you originally wrote it.  Trust me on this fact.

Comment: @nullqube i fix line 6 to k<=48 and still error is occurred can u teach where part is array reach 51?

Comment: @dgnuff  thx for your advice. i am novice for programming however i think this error is irrelevant with variable meaning, is it false?

Comment: Array indices start go from 0 to length minus one. So for `A[50]`, it would be `A[0]` to `A[49]`

Answer (score 1):

int B[50];
and later:
B[50] = 0;

50 isn't a valid index

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
int  N, S,J, K,k,i,j,l,m,n,cnt;

scanf("%d", &k);
int A[50];
int B[50];
if (k <= 50) { // HERE : < 50
    for (i = 1; i < k + 1; i++) { // Why start from 1 instead of 0 ?
        cnt = 0;
        B[50] = 0; // HERE : [50 - 1]
        scanf("%d %d %d %d\n", &N, &S, &J, &K);
        for (j = 0; j < K-1 ; j++) {
            scanf("%d ", &B[j]);
        }
        scanf("%d", &B[K-1]);
        n = (N - S) / J+1;
        for (l = 0;l<= n ; l++) {

                for (m = 0; m < K ; m++) {
                    if (S + (J+1)*l == B[m]) cnt++;
                }

        }

        A[i] = cnt;
    }

    for (i = 1; i < k + 1; i++) {
        printf("#%d %d\n", i, A[i]);
    }

}
return 0;
```

}